# List files ignored by git exclusively by the rules in .git/info/exclude

Tags: git

My repo has a big `.gitignore`. I also have some rules in my `.git/info/exclude` because I do not want my workflow to affect the repo: I use certain tools, and certain processes which generate files, that I do not want to neither be commited to the repo, nor be listed in the `.gitignore`. Those are my "private ignored files".

In a recent project, I have experienced a funny situation: running some tests with some excluded files present break the tests in strange ways. Therefore, before I run the tests (which take hours to run), I need to make sure that I got rid of annoying private files.

Listing all excluded files is not an option:

```
git ls-files --other
```

This produces a list too big for being of any use.

And this:

```
git ls-files --other --exclude-standard
```

Does not list files excluded via the rules of `.git/info/exclude` (or via `.gitignore`)

This does the opposite of what I want:

```
git ls-files -o -X .git/info/exclude
```

Lists all ignore files **except** those in `.git/info/exclude`

This goes in the right direction:

```
git ls-files -o -X .gitignore
```

But then I need to find all `.gitignore` in all folders manually (the repo is very large and has lots of `.gitignore`)

This is nice:

```
git check-ignore -v *
```

But is not recursive, and there is no `recurse` option.

I assume I could diff these two:

```
git ls-files -o
git ls-files -o -X .git/info/exclude
```

But really!? is there no better way to list the files excluded by one particular rule file?

### EDIT

This is the closer I get:

```
find . -type f | git check-ignore -v --stdin | grep '\.git/info/exclude'
```

It only lists files (which I think is what `git` tracks anyway), and it is slow. I would expect an internal `git` command to be faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:

```sh
git ls-files --ignored --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
```

In other words, you forgot to include the [`--ignored`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---ignored) option to show just the ignored files.

The [`--ignored`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---ignored) option is used in conjunction with either `--cached`, to show the ignored files already in the index, or `--others`, to show the ignored untracked files.

Comment: This has a minor flaw in that it will list files that are ignored by *both* one's personal `.git/info/exclude` *and* the existing `.gitignore` files, but there may be no such files (making the flaw nonexistent) and if there are such files it's probably still pretty minor.

Answer (score 2):

Besides [Enrico Compidoglio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69402494/1256452)—which is probably the best way to do this in an automated fashion—you could also temporarily hide (i.e., rename) the `.git/info/exclude` file and use `git ls-files --other --exclude-standard`, then un-hide your personal exclusion file.  The drawback to trying to automate this is that if two entities attempt it "at the same time", or while other Git operations are running, the lack of atomicity shows.  That is, there are three steps involved and the Git repository is therefore in "before", "during", and "after" states and should not be used by anything in the "during" state.

Comment: Nice hack, but a bit brittle. I will use the other solution, even with the minor caveat that you mentioned.